React-three-map zoom and camera controls
can anyone help me about controlling Camera or Zoom on React-three-map with Gsap cause on my projet I give an warning to ask me to add zoom on a plug-in
I'ved added gsap search gsap plug-in but he hasn't this on the package that I have installed

Could you show your attempts so far?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
